# Odoo 13: How do I print the move_id (payment number) in an invoice?

Tags: invoice, odoo-13

I want to add move_id (credit name) or payment_id name from the payments journal to the invoice in report_invoice_document_with_payments or through the payments widget. I have tried several ways without luck and have read payments_ids would work but perhaps the change in Odoo 13 from account.invoice to account.move is the problem since the field is not recognized.

I would like to get something like:
CSH1/2019/0002 Paid on 12/11/2019 $500.00
CSH1/2019/0003 Paid on 12/12/2019 $100.00

The closest I have been is `<t t-esc="payment_vals['payment_id']"/>` in:

````
            <xpath expr="//div[@id='total']/div/table" position="inside">
                <t t-set="payments_vals" t-value="o._get_reconciled_info_JSON_values()"/>
                <t t-foreach="payments_vals" t-as="payment_vals">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <small><i class="oe_form_field text-right oe_payment_label">Paid on <t t-esc="payment_vals['date']"/>,<t t-esc="payment_vals['move_id']"/></i></small>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <span t-esc="payment_vals['amount']" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;monetary&quot;, &quot;display_currency&quot;: o.currency_id}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </t>
                <t t-if="len(payments_vals) &gt; 0">
                    <tr class="border-black">
                        <td><strong>Amount Due</strong></td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                             <span t-field="o.amount_residual"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </t>
            </xpath>
        <xpath expr="." position="attributes"><attribute name="t-name">account.report_invoice_document_with_payments</attribute></xpath></data>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to do it using "ref" (`<i class="oe_form_field text-right oe_payment_label">Paid on <t t-esc="payment_vals['date']"/>,<t t-esc="payment_vals['ref']"/></I>`).

I figured out from account_invoice.py

```
            payment_vals.append({
                'name': payment.name,
                'journal_name': payment.journal_id.name,
                'amount': amount_to_show,
                'currency': currency_id.symbol,
                'digits': [69, currency_id.decimal_places],
                'position': currency_id.position,
                'date': payment.date,
                'payment_id': payment.id,
                'account_payment_id': payment.payment_id.id,
                'invoice_id': payment.invoice_id.id,
                'move_id': payment.move_id.id,
                'ref': payment_ref,
            })
        return payment_vals
```